# Script won't accept argument

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I'm making a script buildt with code from the google ads api. In this script I'm trying to make a new account, and for that to happen, i need to select which manager account the script should be under. That is done with this code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=('Creates a new client under the given manager.'))
# The following argument(s) should be provided to run the example.
parser.add_argument('-m', '--manager_customer_id', type=str,
                    required=True, help='A Google Ads customer ID for the '
                    'manager account under which the new customer will '
                    'be created.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

So when i run the script, i type in `python new_acc.py xxx-xxx-xxxx` and hit enter, and then i get the following error:

```
usage: new_acc.py [-h] -m MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID
new_acc.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--manager_customer_id
```

I have also tried to add the manager_customer_id in the .yaml file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `python new_acc.py -m xxx-xxx-xxxx`?

Comment: @Axe319 that worked, and now i also found out that i didn't need the argument, i could just make it a variable.